# Cirrious.MvvmCross.ExtensionMethods not found in nuget Hot Tuna Starter Pack

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm trying to develop my first application using mvvcross. I'm following this tutorial http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/n0-first-mvvmcross-application-n1-days.html but I don't know why can't use in my code this namespace **Cirrious.MvvmCross.ExtensionMethods**

To add all project's references I'm using Nuget and the version of Hot Tuna Starter Pack is 3.0.10

In this page, http://monodeveloper.org/uncategorized/building-cross-platform-mobile-applications-in-visual-studio-using-xamarin-and-azure-mobile-services/ there is a mvvmcross example, and if I download the source code and add the references that this project is using in the References folder, I can use extensions :(

Like this:

```
var activity = this.GetService<Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Interfaces.IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity;
```

What is the problem? Maybe related with PCL assemblies?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not entirely sure, but `Cirrious.MvvmCross.ExtensionMethods` seems to have been depreceated/left out of version 3 (it is present in the *vNext* branch). By browsing through the version 3 API you might find the equivalents of the missing method in another namespace.

Comment: The finished code for the tutorial is also on https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-00-FirstDemo if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this.GetService<T>` style of service resolution was replaced with simple `Mvx.Resolve<T>` calls and with constructor based dependency injection in MvvmCross v3.

For more information on this, see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control